# How to refer to a ad campaign when adding events in branch.io using api call

Tags: rest, deep-linking, branch.io

io to add custom events in branch but how can i add the reference of ad campaign so that it can be identified in branch this event for a user that has came form specific campaign .i tried using branch sdk it works but when i add event using Rest API call the 3P is not been refered .in documentation also it is not mention how to refer the event to specfic campaign.

https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/reference/events-api

i have attached the URL for the events which i am referring to

I tried by adding developer_identity AND browser_fingerprint_id still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

When an event is created via Branch SDK or API, if you have correctly configured these events that Branch would automatically attribute these events to the campaign or ad link that derived this event conversion. I suggest clicking on an ad link and performing these event within your app and inside [LiveView](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/liveview#getting-started) you can test these conversions and attribution on real time basis. If you are facing issues, it indicates the events are not correctly configured. I suggest submitting a [support ticket](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-ticket) for further assistance.